# Does W3C Widget Checker work?

Tags: web-applications, widget, w3c, w3c-validation

I tried to validate a widget package file with the Alpha version of the [W3C Widget Checker](http://qa-dev.w3.org:8001/widget/), but every-time I hit the button `Check` i get 
`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.` I get that error invariably whether I hit `Check` with an empty URL or a valid URL linking to a package.

Does this online checker works for anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At fist I thought it doesn't work and fails because `Content-Type`, but I respected also the requirements found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/#ta-qxLSCRCHlN, and my tested widget file had `Content-Type` header set to `application/widget` and still it didn't work.

So I think unless someone proves the contrary that the checker is broken.